# How to create TextView with increasing frame size rather than increasing the scroll size when user types

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I need to create two text entry field one beneath  the other. When user types in the upper text field, I need to increase the frame size dynamically (scrolling inside the textview is not recommended.) and the lower text entry frame should go downwards. Will this can be possible in ios? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This may help: http://www.hanspinckaers.com/multi-line-uitextview-similar-to-sms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update the frame of your textView via its contentSize like below:

```
-(void)updateTextViewSize
{
   CGRect rect = textView.frame;
   rect.size.width = textView.contentSize.width;
   rect.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
   textView.frame = rect;

   //lowering the textView2 below this textView
   //assuming that the lower textview touches the 
   //bottom of the upper textView.

   CGRect rect2 = textViewLower.frame;
   rect2.origin.y = textView.frame.origin.y + textView.frame.size.height;

   textViewLower.frame = rect2;

   //update your scrollView here
   //assuming textView and textViewLower are already added to the scrollView

   scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, textViewLower.frame.origin.y + textViewLower.frame.size.height);
}

//implement this delegate method as shown below
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView*)textView
{
  [self updateTextViewSize];
}
```

Comment: Hi I have done like the above, I ve added the two text views inside a scroll view and done like this at the end of function
[_scrolview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, _text1.frame.size.height + _text2.frame.size.height+10)];
Now the problem is when I scrolls the scroll view, the textview frame resets. any idea?

Comment: textViewLower does not exist in Swift 4

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to do resizing of the UITextView to its correct height according to its content using the `UITextView contentSize.`

```
CGRect frame = _textView.frame;
frame.size.height = _textView.contentSize.height;
_textView.frame = frame;
```

Comment: How to determine the content height of the text here?

Comment: It automatically takes the height of the content inside the uitexteview. Did you try the code?